# Using superscript after \middle

Tags: equations, superscripts

I'd like to write this formula with all parenthesis of the same size

```
N = \left( \frac{s}{2} \right)^2 - \left( \frac{d}{2} \right)^2
```

so I tried

```
N = \left( \frac{s}{2} \middle)^2 - \middle( \frac{d}{2} \right)^2
```

The two results are the following:

[image: \middle with superscripts]

Is there a way to achieve my goal without using `\big(` and similar?

Thanks

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  this is probably best addressed by adding a `\vphantom{d}` in the numerator of the first fraction to make it the same height as the second.  (comment rather than answer, since i'm sure this has been answered before.  i'll look for it.)

Comment: Why using `\middle` at all? These cases are *much* better treated with `\big` and friends.

Comment: This is an interesting solution to the problem of different sized parenthesis. I wonder why would `\middle)^2` not output the superscript in the correct position.

Comment: @Manuel Because it's treated internally as if it were `\left`

Comment: @egreg In that case, why does `\left(^2` not put the superscript in the correct position depending of the glyph?

Comment: @Manuel Because `\left` doesn't accept a superscript or subscript field. Ask D. E. Knuth why. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg I think that he could have achieved this “for free” and all would be nice :) In fact I think this is unexpected behaviour (even if he explained it in The TeXbook).

Comment: @Manuel Actually, the final superscript/subscript is relative to the subformula just built, not really to `\right<delim>`.

Comment: @egreg I didn't want to use `\big` because it's a trial and error solution, I'd prefer something more automatic

Comment: @LorenzoCameroni And I ensure you that with some practice you'll be able to get the size right. Avoid `\left` and `\right` as much as you can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the TeXbook, second doubly dangerous paragraph on page 150:

> Question: What happens if a subscript or superscript follows a large delimiter? Answer: That's a good question. After a `\left` delimiter, it is the first subscript or superscript of the enclosed subformula, so it is effectively preceded by `{}`. After a `\right` delimiter, it is a subscript or superscript of the entire `\left...\right` subformula. And after a `\bigl` or `\bigr` or `\bigm` or `\big` delimiter, it applies only to that particular delimiter. Thus, ‘`\bigl(_2|`’ works quite differently from ‘`\left(_2|`’.

From the manual of ε-TeX:

> `\left⟨delim⟩⟨math mode material⟩...\middle⟨delim⟩⟨math mode material⟩...\right⟨delim⟩`
>   (generalizing TeX’s `\left⟨delim⟩⟨math mode material⟩\right⟨delim⟩`). For each `⟨math mode material⟩` ε-TeX begins a new group, starting out with a new math list (always in the same style) that begins with a left boundary item containing everything processed so far. This group must be terminated with either `\middle` or `\right`, at which time the internal math list is completed with a new boundary item containing the new delimiter. In the case of `\middle`, a new group is started again, in the case of `\right`, ε-TeX appends an Inner atom to the current list; the nucleus of this atom contains the internal math list just completed.

From these descriptions, it is clear that `\middle` is actually implemented the same as `\left` (with some tweaks). Subscripts and superscripts are legal after `\right⟨delim⟩`, because they apply to the whole subformula and, in the case of `\middle`, the subformula has not yet been formed.

For your problem, the solution is *not using* `\left` and `\right`, but switching to `\biggl` and `\biggr`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

This is the formula with Barbara's suggestion
\[
N = \left( \frac{s\vphantom{d}}{2} \right)^2 - \left( \frac{d}{2} \right)^2
\]
and here it is with the proper sizes
\[
N = \biggl( \frac{s}{2} \biggr)^{\!2} - \biggl( \frac{d}{2} \biggr)^{\!2}
\]
with a small enhancement too.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Aren't `\Bigl` and `\Bigr` more appropriate here? They are slightly smaller and maybe less invading.

Comment: @pluton I tried them, but didn't like the result. Maybe with `\,` on either side of the fractions…

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive response, now I understand why using `\middle` is not a so good idea.

Answer (score 2):

not finding an earlier question addressing this situation, here is my suggestion:
add a `\vphantom` to the numerator of the fraction on the left to make it appear
to be the same size as the fraction on the right:

```
N = \left( \frac{s\vphantom{d}}{2} \right)^2 - \left( \frac{d}{2} \right)^2
```

Comment: Thanks, this works and made me learn the `\vphantom` macro