# Which way of using parentheses looks better?

Tags: parentheses

I feel like the parentheses look strange here:

```
\begin{equation}
  uv=4\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^2\left(\frac{b}{2}\right)^2=
  4\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)^2\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)^2
\end{equation}
```

Do people think they should have the same heights or be like this?

[image]

Comment: I was about to suggest using `\middle` for the inner brackets, but it turns out that `\middle` [doesn't play well with superscripts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/317024/82389).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you use `\biggl` and `\biggr` in place of `\left` and `\right` it looks great!

```
\begin{equation}
uv=4\biggl(\frac{a}{2}\biggr)^2\biggl(\frac{b}{2}\biggr)^2=4\biggl(\frac{s}{2}\biggr)^2\biggl(\frac{t}{2}\biggr)^2
\end{equation}
```

[image]

The reason why the brackets look a different size is because `a` and `s` are *x-height* letters, whereas `b` and `t` are *ascenders*, so in the latter case the fraction is "taller" and consequently so are the brackets.

Comment: `\biggl` and `\biggr` are better...

Comment: @AndrewSwann It didn't seem to make a visible difference, but good practice nonetheless!

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1232/15925 for the differences...

Comment: And some `^{\!\!2}` in the exponent. I would use probably `\Bigl( .. \Bigr)` so it kind of depends on taste.